# Python re.sub(): expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I'm gathering tweets and filtering each tweet by replacing any words preceded `https://`, `#`, `@` with an empty string. I have a filter function that does just this:

```
def filter(line):
        pattern  = r"(https?://|[@#])\S*"
        s = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
        return s
```

When I try to run this, Python returns this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sia_prefExer02.py", line 36, in <module>
    filteredLine = filter(line)
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sia_prefExer02.py", line 25, in filter
    s = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Line 36 is:
`filteredLine = filter(line)`
Line 25 is: 
`s = re.sub(pattern, '', line)`

What seems to be the problem here?
Is this related rather to the API? I'm using Tweepy.

Comment: What is the value and type (`type(line)`) of `line`?

Comment: We can only tell you the same thing the error message already told you. The thing you're passing to `re.sub` isn't a string.

Comment: By the way, your RegEx looks odd. The Pipe `|` only affects the second forward slash `/` and either `@` or `#`. So it will match `https:/#XYZ`, but not `#XYZ`. Check your parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you are running your `filter(line)` method on each of the tweets.

However based on the [Tweepy docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/getting_started) "Hello Tweepy" example, you should be running it on `tweet.text`:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

If you look in the [API Reference](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#api-reference) you can see that most methods return `Status` objects. (Which is admittedly hard to read code!)

You could wrap you function to work like so and replace line 36 to `filteredLine = filter_tweet(line)`

```
def filter_tweet(status):
    return filter(status.text)
```

---

Side Note: If this is the case, I would rename your line variable to `tweet_status` or something so that you can better guess that it's a `Status` object, not a string.

---

**If this doesn't work** please paste your code, so that we can correctly diagnose the issue. As I'm really going out on a whim here.